# Unable to set optional 'Source Account' on 'Manage Data' operation

Tags: transactions, operations, stellar-laboratory, python-sdk

On all other operations I can use a different 'Source Account', but if I try to do it on 'Manage Data', I get:

- 'tx_failed' when sending with Python-sdk
- no changes applied to XDR if I try it in Laboratory web interface

Am I doing something wrong or is there a bug with transaction builder?

Comment: It works in the Laboratory transaction builder web interface for me.  If I add a source account to the operation, the XDR gets longer.  Moreover, I can verify that the right thing is happening by pasting the generated XDR into `stellar-core --base64 --printtxn -`.  You must be doing something else wrong, or maybe not pasting a syntactically valid account ID.  More information?

Comment: Thank you @user3188445 for your time!

You are saying that it works in transaction builder web interface, however for me it does not. On other operations it works except on 'Manage Data'. Did you try it with 'Manage Data' operation?

I uploaded a video showing how the XDR string does not change when I change 'Source Account'. [link](https://youtu.be/Q2VprrV3-Mc)

I am stuck, dont really know how to solve it. Thanks!

Comment: Oops, somehow you said Manage Data and I managed to read SetOptions.  You are correct that this is a bug in Stellar laboratory.

Comment: Should be fixed after merging https://github.com/stellar/laboratory/pull/335

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug has been fixed: [Laboratory](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/)